# I am not able to execute " cat credentials " on aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, command-line-interface

Using `aws configure` I entered the Access Key, Secret Key and location but after when I try to access the credentials using `cat credentials` I receive an error as:

> credentials: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

The Aws credentials are stored in:

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

Use `cat ~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: @Chaitanya Kaul you are welcome, you can set my answer as solution.